# Android: how to rotate image using Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

I am using Fresco to load images from phone storage by uri into SimpleDraweeView (both internal and external, using content provider - 'content://'). They are loading fine, but keep rotating if they have orientation set in their properties. I tried to set imageRequest with .setAutoRotateEnabled(true) property, but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Any suggestions on how to rotate images to display them properly?

```
imageView.setController(
            controllerBuilder
                    .setOldController(imageView.getController())
                    .setImageRequest(imageRequestBuilder
                            .setSource(uri)
                            .setAutoRotateEnabled(true)
                            .setResizeOptions(null)
                            .build())
                    .build());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue solved by setting .setDownsampleEnabled(false). I don't know why, but I guess that downsampling is REALLY experimantal yet and prevents auto-rotating to happen.

Comment: Yes ，I have same problem~

Comment: I opened issue on Fresco github about this problem, and they said they'll fix it someday (: Hope turning downsampling off helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-rotate is the default, so the image will rotate if the orientation is set. Try setting it to false if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue, where having downsampling enabled in Fresco prevents you from being able to disable auto-rotation of images with EXIF data.

I recently opened an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1247) about this, and the fact that auto-rotation is on by default but this is not documented anywhere, which caused me hours of head-scratching. No response from Fresco devs as yet.

EDIT: The issue is now fixed in Fresco v0.14.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason **setAutoRotateEnabled(true)** also didn't work for me so I forced to always rotate to 90 degrees

**Kotlin code**

```
       val request = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
            .setResizeOptions(ResizeOptions(width, height))
            .setRotationOptions(RotationOptions.forceRotation(RotationOptions.ROTATE_90))
            .build()
```