# How can I rotate image with Fresco Image Viewer library?

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, transform, fresco

I use fresco image viewer library in my app and everything works prefect but I have a problem with rotating image. by default this library can rotate image automatically when the device screen rotation is on but I don't want to use that way.
actually I want to know how can I rotate it by touch or button click in 90 degree and it's very important to work with this library.

This is my code to show image :

```
 ImagePipelineConfig config = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(mContext)
     .setProgressiveJpegConfig(new SimpleProgressiveJpegConfig())
     .setResizeAndRotateEnabledForNetwork(true)
     .setDownsampleEnabled(true)
     .build();
 Fresco.initialize(mContext, config);


 ImageViewer.Builder builder = new ImageViewer.Builder < > (mContext, images);


 builder.setFormatter(new ImageViewer.Formatter < Image > () {
         @Override
         public String format(Image customImage) {
             return customImage.getLarge();
         }
     }).setOverlayView(overlayView)
     .show();
```

https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/FrescoImageViewer

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514161/android-how-to-rotate-image-using-fresco

Comment: i saw that post before but that's not my answer

Answer (score 2):

Example for a 90 degree rotation:

```
ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(URI)
    .setRotationOptions(RotationOptions.forceRotation(RotationOptions.ROTATE_90))
    .build();
```

See also [this example](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/3ed26514e3868c9c7bfc64a1d4d128f0e4bafb32/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/drawee/DraweeRotationFragment.java) in Fresco's Showcase sample app.